# Recovering density parameters from distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable with probability density function $g(x;\theta_1,\theta_2)$, where $g$ is parameterized by two real numbers $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$.  I'd like to specify that
$$
P(a \leq X \leq b) = \int_a^b g(x;\theta_1,\theta_2)\, \mathrm dx = 0.95,
$$
and then recover the parameters $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ that give this.  At first it may seem like there are infinitely many solutions, but I've thought to rewrite this by breaking it up into two equations and using the median of $X$ as a midpoint:
\begin{align*}
\int_a^{median} g(x;\theta_1,\theta_2)\, \mathrm dx & = \frac{0.95}{2}, \\
\int_{median}^b g(x;\theta_1,\theta_2)\, \mathrm dx & = \frac{0.95}{2},
\end{align*}
but I'm stuck from here.

Also, how might this work for densities without a closed-form median, like the [gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) pdf?  Then, is it even possible for pdfs with more than two parameters?

Comment: I think this in some sense "should" have non-uniqueness, since you have one (usually nonlinear) equation in two unknowns. Your method does not work in general because the median is not necessarily halfway between $a$ and $b$ (in the sense that $F(m)$ is not necessarily the average of $F(a)$ and $F(b)$; in fact if it is, then $F(a)$ and $F(b)$ are uniquely determined to be $0.025$ and $0.975$).

Comment: In fact here's an idea. Take $a,b$ given. Choose $A \in (0,0.05)$ to be the value of $F(a)$. *Now* $F$ should actually be determined by the equations $F(a)=A,F(b)=A+0.95$. Now for "a lot" of distributions, there will be a continuum of choices for $A$, given each possible value of $a$. For instance this is true for the normal distribution.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone was curious, I was able to solve this using optimization by minimizing the objective function
$$
(F(b) - F(a) - 0.95)^2 + (F(a) - (1 - F(b))^2
$$
where $F$ is the cdf.  The first term requires that $P(a \leq X \leq b) = 0.95$ and the second requires that $P(X < a) = P(X > b)$, thereby "centering" this $95\%$ interval on the median.

MATLAB's `fmincon` handles this problem nicely.